# Images(Bitmap) are disappearing while drawing on canvas on surfaceview

Tags: android, bitmap, surfaceview

I want to draw 13 different bitmaps on canvas using surface view (obviously, there are some other reasons for using surface view). For this purpose i started a game thread in which i called a method of surface view in infinite loop and in this method I draw 13 different bitmaps in a loop.

But in some phones like Samsung galaxy s3, galaxy s2 and in motorola devices some of my bitmaps are just disappearing after some point of time.

Here is my code for drawing bitmaps :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {              

            // Drawing Bushes
            canvas.drawBitmap(assets.bushes[this.bushes[i].frameNo - 1], null,
                    camera.getScaledRect(bushes[i].bounds.getRect()),
                    bitmapPaint);

            /*
             * drawBitmap(canvas, bushes[i],
             * assets.bushes[this.bushes[i].frameNo - 1], camera);
             */

            // Drawing Waves
            if (waves[i].alpha != 0) {
                bitmapPaint.setAlpha((int) (waves[i].alpha * 255));
                canvas.drawBitmap(assets.waves[this.waves[i].frameNo - 1],
                        null, camera.getScaledRect(waves[i].bounds.getRect()),
                        bitmapPaint);
                bitmapPaint.setAlpha(255);
            }    

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here may be an answer. The older devices might not keep up. Just try down sampling your bitmaps. This has increased the performance for me. It seems the screen is wiped when its intensive. Although the quality is lost a bit.

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

public static int calculateInSampleSize( BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight);

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight)